# Propagating a change of variable done by a sub-executed script

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, debian, sh

My problem is self-descripting:

script1.sh contains:

```
#!/bin/sh
export SOMEVAR=0
echo "1, SOMEVAR=$SOMEVAR"
./script2.sh
echo "2, SOMEVAR=$SOMEVAR"
```

script2.sh contains:

```
#!/bin/sh
SOMEVAR=1
```

./script1.sh gives:

```
1, SOMEVAR=0
2, SOMEVAR=0
```

while I would like:

```
1, SOMEVAR=0
2, SOMEVAR=1
```

How can I obtain the wanted result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `source` (aka. `.`) instead of calling the script, child processes cannot change parents environment:

```
#!/bin/sh
export SOMEVAR=0
echo "1, SOMEVAR=$SOMEVAR"
. ./script2.sh
echo "2, SOMEVAR=$SOMEVAR"
```